# D8 render a contact form from theme preprocess

Tags: 8, theming, emails

I want to render a form in a node view. I made an entity reference to a contact form, then in the preprocess_node I'm trying to get the render array of the contact form.

```
function mysupertheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

  if ($node->getType() == 'mynodetype') {
    if (!empty($node->field_mynodetype_form->referencedEntities())) {
      $contact_form = $node->field_mynodetype_form->referencedEntities()[0];
      $message = \Drupal::entityManager()
      ->getStorage('contact_message')
      ->create(array(
        'contact_form' => $contact_form->id(),
      ));

      //$form = \Drupal::entityFormBuilder()->getForm($message);
    };
  }
}
```

I don't know how to call entityFormBuilder in preprocess. Is this the right way to do this ? How can I display a choosen contact form in a node ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work when this patch is implemented:

[Add a view builder for contact_form](https://www.drupal.org/node/2615112)

Comment: Right direction, but what you actually want to write is "Your code will no longer be needed because it will just work with that patch :)"

Comment: I believe that patch should've gotten into 8.1.0, but it doesn't "just work" from what I can tell. I have the field set to "Rendered View" since that is the only formatter that is available aside from Label and Entity ID. That gives an error of `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in Drupal\views\Element\View::preRenderViewElement() (line 49 of ..../core/modules/views/src/Element/View.php).`

Comment: @nicholas.alipaz, it is now planned for 8.2, in the meantime it is in https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_storage (and see Berdir's comment, you probably don't need any code)

Comment: +1 for contact_storage as the stop-gap solution before drupal core fixes it. I do like the other features of contact_storage too. A new display formatter is available for a contact form entity reference called rendered entity after the module is enabled. Thanks!